# How to write regex express string literal in scala

Tags: regex, scala, string-literals

String litertal consist zero or more character enclosed by double quote(").
Use escape sequences(listed below) to represent special characters within a string.
It is a compile-time error for a newline or EOF characterto appear inside a string literal.
All the supported escape sequences are as follow:

- \b backspace
- \f formfeed
- \r carriage return
- \n newline
- \t tab
- \"    double quote
- \ backslash

The following are valid examples of string literal:

- " This is a string contain tab \t"
- " Hello stackoverflow \"\b"

Can you help me write a regex match string literal?
Thanks so much.

Comment: If you show what have you tried so far.

Comment: What do you mean by "express string literal" ? It is not obvious what you want ?

Comment: write a regex match string literal. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

The most general way is to use [`Pattern.quote()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) method which returns a regular expression that matches the literal string passed as its argument. You can use it in Scala as well as in Java.

Comment: my project require use regex.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match e.g. the string represented by the literal `"contain tab \t"`, you would use the regexp `"contain tab \t".r`—so, there is no need for any special handling of TAB inside the regexp.

Comment: can you write full regex for this requirement?